# Display a default image for custom-logo

Tags: customization, genesis-theme-framework, logo

I am switching my Genesis theme over to use Wordpress' 4.5 custom-logo function. It was simple to do:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
    'width'           => 861,
    'height'          => 130,
    'flex-width'      => true,
    'flex-height'     => true,
) );
```

However, I do not see a way in which to provide a default logo (which would be under `theme/images/header.svg` where `customer-header` had had an option like:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
    'default-image' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/header.png',
    ...
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to do? I am willing to edit the child theme, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you display the custom logo you can check if is set, if not you display another image. You can achieve this with the following code featured in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-logo/). I adapted it to suit your needs:

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
if ( has_custom_logo() ) {
        echo '<img src="'. esc_url( $logo[0] ) .'">';
} else {
        echo '<img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/header.png' .'">';
}
```